# Unable to resolve an array in Castle Windsor

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I cannot get Castle Windsor (3.0) to resolve an array. I've done it before and I have other arrays resolved, so this is confounding.

First I add a `CollectionResolver`, which does arrays

```
_container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(_container.Kernel));
```

Then, I register all my classes based on this interface, of which there are about 6

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ISearchSource>());
```

They are definitely in the same assembly and in the debugger, I can see these classes are in the list of components eg.

```
public class ViewsSearchSource : ISearchSource {...}
```

Yet in the class that resolves this, like this...

```
public SearchBot(ISearchSource[] searchSources)
```

I get

> 'SearchBot' is waiting for the following dependenciesService 'ISearchSource[]' which was not registered.

I've even tried adding an `ArrayResolver` (as well as `CollectionResolver`) explicitly. Same error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

AllInterfaces is necessary due to your dependency is on interface type: "AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn()" picks all types implementing ISearchSource, but those types will be registered in the container with the concrete type, not with the interface(which has been used instead as dependency).

PS: I suggest you to use Classes instead of AllTypes.

"WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()" should be enough in your case.

Keep in mind windsor resolves dependencies according to registration: IOW you have to flag(during component registration) your concrete with all its interface you will use as dependency.

While you are in debug, add a watch/breakpoint on the container to see all registered component and the interface/concrete "linked/assigned" to you component: that unveil the magic behind the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to register like this

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ISearchSource>().WithService.AllInterfaces());
```

ie had to add `WithService.AllInterfaces());`

I actually don't understand why this AllInterfaces is necessary here, but it works.